# Set Headers using append or set does not work in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am using Angular 2.4.8. I want to append custom headers to each request. I am using `BaseRequestOptions` to define custom headers and adding it to app providers. Following is the code.

```ts
import { BaseRequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppBaseRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  public merge(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('My-Custom-Header', 'My-Custom-Header-Value');
    return super.merge(headers);
  }
}
```

Provider is as follows.

```ts
providers: [
    { provide: BaseRequestOptions, useClass: AppBaseRequestOptions }
  ]
```

I have tried `headers.append` and `headers.set` but both throws

`Cannot read property 'append' of null` 
`Cannot read property 'set' of null`

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget?

```ts
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
```

Comment: I think headers.append should add headers to existing headers, but it does not. Im just worried to know that by creating new Headers() should not override the existing headers list.

Comment: existing headers? that is null?