# HttpHeaders set vs. append in Angular

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-httpclient

I have a caching interceptor that checks if the request has an `x-refresh` header present.  If so, it ignores any cached request/response combo for this endpoint and goes to the server.  However, when I use it in a service call, I have to use the `append(...)` method instead of the `set(...)` method on Angular's `HttpHeaders` class.  I couldn't figure out from the documentation or online searches why that is.  `req.headers.get(x-refresh)` returns what I would expect only if `append('x-refresh', '')` is used.  `req.headers.get('x-refresh')` doesn't return anything if I use `set('x-refresh', '')`.  Why is that?  I looked at the source code for this and I don't see anything that would change this behavior, but I'm assuming it is something I overlooked.

What is the difference between set and append other than set will overwrite the header with that key if it already exists, otherwise set it, whereas append will append to that header if it is allowed to append to that header?

Comment: Please, if you want me to close this question, tell me why.  I'm not allowed to ask this question on Angular's GitHub page, and they ask me to come here to StackOverflow.  If I'm doing something wrong, I'd be happy to fix the issue.  I'm interested in getting help, not being annoying.  Thanks.

Comment: angular's github page is to report bugs with angular, not provide community support that you get here. As a community member I'd suggest you close this question..main reason being you started with some description of how you did some code debugging (without providing full code / context)..then you launched into asking a general question about how the mechanisms are supposed to work. For the latter you can read the angular docs for a broader understanding. For a specific answer you ask a more specific question with code!

Comment: Yes, I know what the purpose of the GitHub page is.  That's why I said what I said in my comment ... last year.  I mention in my question that I ALREADY read the documentation and did further searching for an answer.  Where would you prefer that I ask this question?  By yelling into the sky?  Also, you seem to have misunderstood the intent of the structure of my question here.  I ask my originally intended question at the end, providing background and context prior.  One last point: I don't believe MORE code will help here.  I provided enough code, and all that's missing is a class declaration

Answer (score 3):

The `append()` method of the Headers interface appends a new value onto an existing header inside a Headers object, or adds the header if it does not already exist.

The difference between `set()` and `append()` is that if the specified header already exists and accepts multiple values, `set()` will overwrite the existing value with the new one, whereas `append()` will append the new value onto the end of the set of values.

Answer (score 1):

All I was trying to say in my comment is that given that the impetus for your question is solving the coding challenge, posting the code helps the community answer your question and share knowledge. i.e. ask a good question, get a good answer.

However, if you just want someone to explain the differences between set vs. append, you're asking to assume you don't have a problem elsewhere in your code, when *what you really want to know is why didn't 'set' work in your implmentation*. i.e. you're not ultimately interested in the general differences.

For all we know maybe your syntax is off on some line of code not posted. Check out this related question to see an example of this: [Set Headers using append or set does not work in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555482/set-headers-using-append-or-set-does-not-work-in-angular-2). It's also possible there was a bug on set vs. append in a particular angular version that you bumped into. In either event I hope you can see why it doesn't help to focus on generalities.

When you post code, better yet put it on stackblitz etc. it allows community members to better respond since we see the full picture (preceding code, angular version etc.), and trouble-shoot from different angles. Moreover, if there is a reproducible bug, perhaps it actually warrants a ticket on github for the angular project itself.

Comment: Your assumptions can be right, but maybe he thinks that he just needs to understand the difference between both options to solve it by himself. Or for any other reason, I don't see why a question can't be about the general differences instead of a specific implementation.